# Find all files in folder containing strings from given file (Python)

Tags: python

I have a folder with lots of files, some of them contain one or several keywords, I also have a separate file, consisting of keywords only, a word per line, like this:

```
keyword1
keyword2
keyword3
```

I need to find all of these files.

So I have this code

```
import os

directory = os.listdir("D:/where_2_search")

with open('what_2search.txt','r') as searchlist:
    for line in searchlist:
    print(line)
    for fname in directory:
        if os.path.isfile("D:/where_2_search" + os.sep + fname):
            searchedfile = open("D:/where_2_search" + os.sep + fname, 'r')
            if line in searchedfile.read():
                print('found string in file %s' % fname)
            else:
                print('string not found')
            searchedfile.close()
```

But it doesn't work as I receive negative results only. How could I fix it?

Comment: this could just be in the sample, but watch your indentation

Answer (score 1):

I think the best module to use is [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html). You can simply read the keywords from file and get list of files that matches the keywords.

**NOTE** Not tested. I recommend you to do yourself. This is just a help/overview.

```
from glob import glob
import os

with open('what_2search.txt','r') as searchlist:
    keywords= searchlist

found_files = []
# You might want to change the working directory as follow if needed
os.chdir(path_where_those_files_are)
for keyword in keywords:
    found_files.append(glob(keyword)) # Here is a little bug. But can easily sort this out

print(found_files) # List of files needed
```

Answer (score 0):

You have newlines at the end of your keywords

try changing to this

```
if line.rstrip() in searchedfile.read():
```

Comment: Doesn't change a thing, sory.

Comment: Strange.  I've verified it fixes the issue on my system.